# Slow connection of Visual Studio 2010 c++ with MySql

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, youtube

I watched the youtube video's up to: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hofIXcoxlHQ&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZz6uDid--I09EOImRmPHS0&index=6
(including the beginner course MYSQL with install notes)
The log-in form works. 
BUT in the beginning of the video the shown log-in form responds in 1-2 seconds, while my system replies after 13 seconds.
WHY?

I have a very fast pc. (Windows 7 (64) on a 4 core  i7 CPU 920 with 6GB memory.)

Answer (score 0):

found answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/408550/connecting-to-mysql-from-php-is-extremely-slow
should use datasource=127.0.0.1 not datasource=local host.